# In Xcode, how to disable the handling of macros for indentation?

Tags: c, xcode, indentation

In Xcode 4.0, by default, the indentation is like below:

```
#ifdef SYNTHETIC
    char buff_inarray[100];
#else
    char buff_in;
#endif
```

However, I want it to be the simpler version, like:

```
    #ifdef SYNTHETIC
    char buff_inarray[100];
    #else
    char buff_in;
    #endif
```

How to set it?

Comment: Hah. In this case I agree with Xcode. Which is unusual. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't modify Xcode indentation settings. You'll have to either use a different editor and re-indent all code yourself.

Maximum you can do, is disable autoindent. It is done in Xcode's preferences → Text Editing → Indentation. This pic is from Xcode 5, but I'm pretty sure version 4 had it there as well.

[image: Autoindent settings]

Also, it is a common coding convention to use preprocessor macros from column 0, all programmers would expect it be there. The reason being it's not code itself (which *should* be indented), it is which code is to be compiled.